# Cassandra Data Modeling - Access Pattern involving more than two entities

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, datastax

This question might be a very obvious thing or an anti-pattern as well however I could not find authoritative information through my searches hence posting it here.

Consider that there are three entities

> Users
>     
> -id
>     
> -name
>     
> -email
>     
> ...
>   
> Videos
>     
> -id
>     
> -title
>     
> -type
>     
> ...
>   
> Actors
>     
> -id
>     
> -name
>     
> ...

Relationships and Cardinalities:

> Users--1----m--Videos
>   
> Videos--n----m--Actors

How should I model for following access pattern/query?

> *Find videos uploaded by given user and featuring given actor*

**Edit**:
When I searched over internet, I am getting only such examples of access patterns that involve either one or maximum two related entities. Unable to determine whether such access pattern that touches more than two entities is invalid/anti-pattern or one should follow same modeling technique in this scenario as well.

regards,

Aniket

Answer (score 2):

I have little experience with Cassandra but I've been working hard on it for the last week, so I'll give it a try.

```
CREATE TABLE videos_by_user(
    user_name TEXT,
    user_email TEXT STATIC,
    actor TEXT,
    video_id INT,
    video_type TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_name), actor, video_id)
);
```

`user_name` is the partition key, so a request like "Find all videos uploaded by a given user" is trivial and returns a single partition:

```
SELECT * FROM videos_by_user WHERE user_name = 'Joe';
```

`actor` is a clustering key (one `actor` is one row in the partition) and each one of them stores a reference to the video, and as it doesn't hurt to duplicate some data, `video_type` is duplicated for each actor. You can then do queries like

```
SELECT * FROM videos_by_user WHERE user_name = 'Joe' AND actor = 'John';
```

The properties that belong to users are declared as `static` and are not duplicated: `user_email` is a single value per partition (ie. per user). Imagine that you want to email a link to a certain user as he's suddenly interested the videos with some actor:

```
SELECT user_email, video_id FROM videos_by_user WHERE user_name = 'Joe' AND actor = 'John';
```

I'm also interested in what other might think of this solution. Did I do my homeworks rights?

Comment: Nice and useful thought on the data model involving more than two entities. I had similar notion of table design where attributes from three entities would need to be combined.

Only change in above design could be to include video_id also as part of primary key, either as a clustering column or part of partition key,  mainly to avoid UPSERTs. If we do not include video_id in primary key then vid1 uploaded by "joe" and actor "john" would be replaced by vid2 uploaded by "joe" and actor "john". 

I am still wondering isn't such access pattern very common that involves more than two entities?

Comment: When I searched over internet, I am getting only such examples of access patterns and models that involve either one or maximum two related entities. Unable to determine whether such access pattern that accesses more than two entities is invalid/anti-pattern or one should follow same modeling technique in this scenario as well.

Comment: Indeed, I'll update the answer for the problem of having more than one video with same actor belonging to the same user. For the rest I'm having a hard time finding such info as well.